# Color function to return a shade lighter and a shade darker

Tags: java, android, android-layout, colors

Say I give the function a simple blue. Then it should return the hex code or RGB for dark blue, and for light blue. I am working in Java/android

Comment: Well here is an answer to your question, lightest blue is white and darkest is black.

Comment: It's really pretty easy if you try. Have you tried? What have you tried? (Inferring that your question is "How do I do this?")

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon even if the question is trivial and against rules, you could bother to read more than the title.

Comment: @MightyPork - I did - and it all comes down to *what is a shade?* What is *dark blue*? What is *light blue*? What would *a shade* darker than black be? What is *a shade* lighter than light blue? What is *a shade* lighter than that? ...

Comment: Yes, the title is ambiguous. But terms "dark" and "light" are quite easy to imagine, if you think outside RGB. In HSL it's simply different values of L.

Comment: Some people use "light/dark" to refer to "pale/bold", also. A pastel color, for instance, could be made "darker" by raising saturation.

Comment: You're right, it's only an assumption - based on that the question says 'simple blue'. I believe it means `0x0000FF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way is to convert it to [HSL color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), adjust the "lightness" component, and convert back to RGB.

I found two pages where are mentioned formulas you might use, or you can just try to google a java solution.

**[RGB to HSL](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm)**

**[HSL to RGB](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hsl-to-rgb.htm)**

---

Another option is to use [YUV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV), for which the calculations are easier.

In YUV color space you can adjust darkness by changing the Y value.

**RGB to YUV**

```
Y =  (0.257 * R) + (0.504 * G) + (0.098 * B) + 16

V =  (0.439 * R) - (0.368 * G) - (0.071 * B) + 128

U = -(0.148 * R) - (0.291 * G) + (0.439 * B) + 128
```

**YUV to RGB**

```
B = 1.164(Y - 16)                  + 2.018(U - 128)

G = 1.164(Y - 16) - 0.813(V - 128) - 0.391(U - 128)

R = 1.164(Y - 16) + 1.596(V - 128)
```

*However, you must clamp the 'YUV' and 'RGB' values to 0-255*
(try `value = value & 0xFF`)

([source](http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into the links. Never heard of HSL before.

Comment: Instead of HSL could I use HSV? and simply change the V value?

Comment: That really depends on what you consider 'shade'. HSL can easily make the color darker or lighter. HSV can do other things. I think what you want is really HSL, but you can try both and see which fits better.

Comment: YUV can be handy, too. You'd want to mess *mostly* with the Y value there.

Comment: @Geobits thanks for widening my horizons! YUV would be good indeed - I'll add it to the answer.